# How can I add an array item to nested reducer object?

Tags: javascript, redux

I am trying to build a chat app using firebase, react-native and redux. I have messages collection which is very simple as you can see below.

#### Firebase - Data structure

```
"messages": {
    "-LZtqlYn2WB_1E-u4gUk-LZtqlYn2WB_1E-u4gUo": {
      "-LZv3-yzpZ88lCLkGyRT": {
        "createdAt": 1551474102199,
        "receiverId": "-LZtqlYn2WB_1E-u4gUo",
        "senderId": "-LZtqlYn2WB_1E-u4gUk",
        "text": "alls"
      }
    },
    "-LZtqlYn2WB_1E-u4gUo-L_8ymxVU_bS8r9Rux4y": {
      "-L_8z5l0mNgJodbdh07O": {
        "createdAt": 1551724473404,
        "receiverId": "-LZtqlYn2WB_1E-u4gUo",
        "senderId": "-L_8ymxVU_bS8r9Rux4y",
        "text": "asfasfsf"
      }
    }
  }
```

In case of you didn't notice, messages has long unique id which is a combination of receiverId and senderId. I call it **conversationId**.

#### What do I want?

So, let's say we have a user who has two conversations between other users. I want to store this user's conversations in a reducer **as an array of objects**, identified by **conversationId**.

#### Redux action

```
export const addMessage = (id, data) => ({
  type: MESSAGE_RECEIVED,
  id,
  data,
});

export const fetchMessages = (conversationId, userId) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(fetchingMessages());

  const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

  rootRef
    .child('messages')
    .child(conversationId)
    .on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
      const message = snapshot.val();

      dispatch(
        addMessage(conversationId, {
          id: snapshot.key,
          date: moment(message.createdAt),
          isReceiver: message.receiverId === userId,
          message: message.text,
        }),
      );
    });
};
```

#### Redux reducer

```
import { MESSAGE_RECEIVED } from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  payload: {},
  isLoading: false,
};

export default function messagesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
      return {
        ...state,
        payload: {
          ...state.payload,
          [action.id]: [...state.payload[action.id], action.data],
        },
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

#### My problem

I'm having difficulties with messages reducer. I think, I don't have clear information about the spread operator. This is what I got when I run my code.

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
```

#### What I expect from the reducer output

```
{
    "isLoading": false,
    "payload": {
        "-LZtqlYn2WB_1E-u4gUk-LZtqlYn2WB_1E-u4gUo": [
            {
                "id": "-L_X_0ekmluKjxG8gaje",
                "isReceiver": true,
                "message": "hi!"
            },
            {
                "id": "-LZv3RaUTUD6KQczYGJX",
                "isReceiver": false,
                "message": "hey!"
            }
        ],
        "-LZtqlYn2WB_1E-u4gUo-L_8ymxVU_bS8r9Rux4y": [
            {
                "id": "LZv3RaUTRY6KQxzYMJL",
                "isReceiver": false,
                "message": "hi!"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am assuming state.payload[action.id] is not iterable. {} or numbers would give you this error. Can you post what is the value of state.payload[action.id]

Comment: It is `undefined` because I haven't created that [action.id] object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an absolute idiot. After tarzen asked me the value of state.payload[action.id], I realized I could just write an if statement. Here is the working reducer code:

```
import { MESSAGE_RECEIVED } from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  payload: [],
  isLoading: false,
};

export default function messagesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MESSAGE_RECEIVED: {
      if (state.payload[action.id]) {
        return {
          ...state,
          isLoading: false,
          payload: {
            ...state.payload,
            [action.id]: [...state.payload[action.id], action.data],
          },
        };
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        payload: {
          ...state.payload,
          [action.id]: [action.data],
        },
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```